# How many vtables gets created in below program?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vtable

I have seen few exmples showing vtables concepts in stackoverflow but given examples are only for single class, when we derived class from two abstract classes then how many vtables will be created for that class?

```
class A {
 public :
         virtual void func_1() = 0;
};

class B {
 public :
         virtual void func_2() = 0;
};

class C : public A, public B {
  public :
          void func_1()
          {
            cout << "func_1" << endl;
          }
          void func_2()
          {
            cout << "func_2" << endl;
};
```

In above example how many vtables will be there for class C, and will class A and class B have any vtables??

Comment: In which implementation? "Vtables" are not a C++ language feature.

Comment: And why do you want to know? Why not code to standards/abstractions and be happy :)

Comment: This really depends on the implementation like LRIO points out and also the code you are using.  If the compiler can prove certain conditions it can optimize away the run-time code and instead use a static function call to the appropriate function.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case, C has one vtable and A and B have none.  You can see this for yourself by out-of-lining C's member functions, so that the vtable will actually be emitted, and correcting the other compile errors:

```
extern "C" int puts(const char *);

struct A { virtual void func_1() = 0; };
struct B { virtual void func_2() = 0; };

struct C : A, B
{
  void func_1();
  void func_2();
};

void C::func_1() { puts("func_1"); }
void C::func_2() { puts("func_2"); }
```

... compiling to an object file, and then looking at the symbols:

```
$ gcc -c test.cc
$ nm test.o | c++filt
                 U puts
0000000000000000 T C::func_1()
000000000000001a T C::func_2()
0000000000000033 T non-virtual thunk to C::func_2()
0000000000000000 V typeinfo for A
0000000000000000 V typeinfo for B
0000000000000000 V typeinfo for C
0000000000000000 V typeinfo name for A
0000000000000000 V typeinfo name for B
0000000000000000 V typeinfo name for C
0000000000000000 V vtable for C
                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info
```

The compiler can prove that only the basic vtable for C is necessary because none of the classes have data or nontrivial constructors, and because A and B can't be instantiated directly.  In the general case, there might be multiple vtables for all three classes.  The exact rules for when multiple vtables are necessary are very complicated and I'm not going to try to summarize them here.  They are spelled out in the ["Itanium" C++ ABI](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html), sections 2.5 and 2.6, but they probably won't make much sense if you're not accustomed to reading standardese *and* deeply familiar with the dark corners of C++; unfortunately I am not aware of any good overview of this for beginners.  (It's been historically assumed that either you don't care or you are already an expert.)  ("Itanium" is in quotes above because the spec was *written* with Itanium in mind, but the design was then adopted very widely.  Unless you're using MSVC, you are probably getting this C++ ABI.)  (To illustrate just how dark these dark corners are: I *helped write* this ABI spec, and yet I have no freaking idea why GCC thinks it needs to emit a "non-virtual thunk to C::func_2".)

Comment: "_Unless you're using MSVC, you are probably getting this C++ ABI._" Are you sure other Windows compilers do *not* follow MSVC?

Comment: @curiousguy They would have had to reverse engineer it.  The LLVM people did in fact do this, and *very recent* Clang is mostly compatible with MSVC, but it was a gigantic effort.  GCC doesn't even try.  I don't know about Intel's compilers -- if anyone could squeeze the actual spec out of Microsoft it would be Intel, but I kinda doubt they bothered.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know for sure is to compile it and look, but in this case it's a virtual certainty that there will only be 1 vtable (maybe even 0 if you don't export the class). If either of the base classes weren't abstract the answer would be different depending on the compiler.

Comment: It depends how you count the vtables. There are two vtables here: one for A and one for B.